# Xcode Organizer asking "Please verify the email address associated with your Apple ID"

Tags: ios, xcode, organizer

Randomly tonight i tried to submit an app via xcode organizer. And this pops up...

[image: Please verify the email address associated with your Apple ID]

Anyone run into this before? Any ideas how to fix it? I can log into appleid.apple.com, developer.apple.com and so on with no issues as I have been doing for years.

Comment: Logging in is not verifying. Log in _and verify_. Just do what it says. What's the problem?

Comment: your talking about logging into appleid.apple.com? If so I did but still get the same message.

Comment: Because you didn't verify. You have to go to your settings page and ask it to do the verification.

Comment: I see no "settings" page at https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage. It does have some account details and if i try to edit sections i still see no where to re-verify.

Comment: Me too have same issue from today morning but not Randomly always this is happening, can't export the app.

Comment: Correct. It is not random. It is something that never happened for the past few years while using my ID. But today it decided my ID was no longer "verified"? Might be an issue with apple. I will see if it works in the morning. If it does not I will try removing the apple ID from xcode and add it again.

Comment: i have the same problem… seems like that's an app store server problem…

Comment: I have the same problem.... it is a new happenned...

Comment: Same here since this morning...

Comment: i am also facing this problem from morning..cannot archive to make build.Its really strange error..

Comment: same here, just noticed

Comment: Same issue from this morning. Yesterday I could upload to iTunesConnect without any problem.

Comment: Same here, does anyone find some walk around or fix?

Comment: One of my colleague had a same symptom. It is really weird that we use the same apple enterprise account. I still can extract ipa with the apple id but not my colleague.

Comment: And are you able to run validate in Xcode Organizer?

Comment: No, running validate also shows the same alert message.

Comment: Anyone having this issue still give the answer I posted a try!

Comment: Same issue here since this morning... -.-"

Answer (score 18):

Removing the accounts, and adding them back in preferences produced the same alert. But... removing all accounts then attempting to submit via organizer brought up a new dialog that allowed me to add my ID again. Doing that allowed me to upload again!

Comment: Worked to me too. Export and import all accounts didn't work.

Comment: Worked for me as well

Comment: This worked for me. Going to `appleid.apple.com` and trying verify multiple accounts didnt..

Answer (score 18):

I have multiple (four actually) Apple ID's registered in Accounts. It turned out, that one of those accounts needed verification. I simply tried to log on with every account I have at appleid.apple.com until I got:

[image]

After verification, the problem was solved.

Comment: This worked for me! :) Anyway, they could specify in the error message which account needs to be verified -.-"

Comment: This worked for me. I have 10 accounts and 8 of them needed to be verified. Works fine now.

Comment: Had to wait a little while before Xcode believed all of the accounts had been verified.

Comment: I could enter this page to verify email :(

Comment: You've just saved me from going nuts... :)

Comment: after verification you need to quit xcode and open it again and go to accounts. Then you have to login to accounts where session expired. Then you can open organizer export. cheers!

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. I just removed all Accounts in Preferences, and adding all Apple ID's again and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing the same answer **Removing *all* the Accounts** from Xcode Preferences. Accounts means all the accounts added in preferences, i.e. it won't work if you have more than one account there and try to remove and re-adding a particular account from that list.

Answer (score 0):

If the remove and add account again does not work, and in particular if you have multiple accounts: just use Application Loader until Apple fix this ! :) Work find with Application Loader.

For Application Loader, you need an IPA. Don't use Xcode ipa generation system. Prefer manual creation of ipa by 1) zipping 2 folders : a Payload folder that contain your .app and a SwiftSupport folder that you can copy from your Xarchive. The 2) rename the zip to .ipa.